# Removing currency character from NumberFormat format()

Tags: java, groovy, formatting

Am trying to remove the currency character after formatting the currency using NumberFormat

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

BigDecimal currencyAmount = new BigDecimal(9876543.21)
def currentLocale = Locale.US
def currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentLocale);

println "formatted currency = "+currencyFormatter.format(currencyAmount)
```

This prints `$9,876,543.21` but I dont want $ or any currency character in the formatted currency. Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Groovy Solution:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat

def currencyAmount = 9876543.21 //Default is BigDecimal
def currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getInstance( Locale.US )

assert currencyFormatter.format( currencyAmount ) == "9,876,543.21"
```

Don't need `getCurrencyInstance()` if currency is not requried.

Comment: This doesn't work with whole numbers: `5280` will be `5,280` and not `5,280.00` which is what op was wanting.